# Navigation Controller Clear in Unwind Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a segue connecting two views. In the parent view, the navigation bar is a gray color, and in the child view, it's clear. When unwinding the segue, the navigation bar in the parent controller is now clear as well. How to fix this?

Parent Controller

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.title = "FEED"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(white:0.97, alpha:1.0)
    let navBarLineView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,
        CGRectGetHeight((navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)!),
        CGRectGetWidth((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)!),
        1))
    navBarLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.91, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(navBarLineView)
}
```

Child Controller

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.title = "Space
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting background and shadow images to `nil` in `viewWillDisappear` method in the child controller worked fine for me when I wanted to restore default style of navigation bar:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
}
```